# Fast way to lookup entries with duplicates

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a way to help me quickly look up duplicate entries in some sort of table structure in a very efficient way. Here's my problem:

I have objects of type `Cargo` where each `Cargo` has a list of other associated `Cargo`. Each cargo also has a type associated with it.

so for example:

```
class Cargo {
   int cargoType;
   std::list<Cargo*> associated;
}
```

now for each cargo object and its associated cargo, there is a certain value assigned to it based on their types. This evaluation happens by classes that implement `CargoEvaluator`.

Now, I have a `CargoEvaluatorManager` which basically handles connecting everything together. `CargoEvaluators` are registered with `CargoEvaluatorManager`, then, to evaluate cargo, I call `CargoEvaluatorManager.EvaluateCargo(Cargo* cargo)`.

**Here's the current state**

```
class CargoEvaluatorManager{
std::vector<std::vector<CargoEvaluator*>> evaluators;

double EvaluateCargo(Cargo* cargo)
{
   double value = 0.0;
   for(auto& associated : cargo->associated) {
      auto evaluator =  evaluators[cargo->cargoType][associated->cargoType];
      if(evaluator != nullptr)
          value += evaluator->Evaluate(cargo, associated);
    }

    return value;
}
}
```

So to recap and mention a few extra points:

- `CargoEvaluatorManager` stores `CargoEvaluators` in a 2-D array using cargo types as indices. The entire 2d vector is initialized with nullptrs. When a `CargoEvaluator` is registered, resizing the array and the other bits and peieces I haven't shown here are handled appropriately.
- I had tried using a map with std::pair as a key to look up different evaluators, but it is too slow.
- This only allows one `CargoEvaluator` per combination of `cargotype`. I want to have multiple cargo evaluators potentially as well.
- I am calling this `EvaluateCargo` tens and billions of times. I am aware my current implementation is not the most efficient and am looking for alternatives.

**What I am looking for**

As stated above, I want to do much of what I've outlined with the exception that I want to allow multiple `Evaluators` for each pair of `Cargo` types. As I envision it, naively, is a table like this :

```
--------------------------------------------
|int type 1  | int type 2 | CaroEvaluator* |
|------------------------------------------|
|   5        |     7      |    Eval1*      |
|   5        |     7      |    Eval2*      |
|   4        |     6      |    Eval3*      |
--------------------------------------------
```

- The lookup should be symmetric in that the set `(5,7)` and `(7,5)` should resolve to the same entries. For speed I don't mind preloading duplicate entries.
- There are maybe 3x or more more associated `Caro` in the list than there are `Evaluators`, if that factors into things.
- Performance is crucial, as mentioned above!
- For *bonus points*, each cargo evaluator may have an additional `penalty` value associated with it, that is not dependent on how many `Associates` a `Cargo` has. In other words: if a row in the table above is looked up, I want to call `double Evaluator->AddPenality()` **once and only once** each time `EvaluateCargo` is called. I cannot store any instance variables since it would cause some multithreading issues.
- One added constraint is I need to be able to identify the `CargoEvaluators` associated with a particular `cargotype`, meaning that hashing the two cargotypes together is not a viable option.

If any further clarification is needed, I'll gladly try to help.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: std::unordered_multimap

Comment: How do I resolve the issue of needing a pair for a key without using std::pair? I have found it (pair, that is) to be very slow as compared to a simple primitive type for a key.

Comment: Can you use a 64 bit integer (long long) to wrap the 2 int's in a single primitive?

Comment: You should profile and see where the bottleneck is, eliminate it and move to the next bottleneck. "std::pair is slow as a key" is a meaningless sentence by itself (not accompanied by profile data).

Comment: @n.m. I have profiled.  This is more or less the tightest loop in my application. My initial implementation, about 4 months ago, was  a std::map using a std::pair as a key, but after profiling with valgrind, I found that creating and destroying the pair for lookup in that scope was far slower (I don't recall the percentage to be honest, but it was significant enough for me to change) that my implementation above.

Comment: @pragmatist1- that's why I suggested using a 64bit primitive. No construction, no memory allocation/deallocation, simple hashing..

Comment: Amit: do you recommend a particular approach to hashing? i

Comment: You might be able to design custom hashing if there are particular features about your cargo types that would be suitable, but I focused on preventing non primitive types. Standard hashing implementations should be quite optimized for linear distributed keys

Comment: After playing around with this, I realize for other reasons I require the ability to identify `Evaluators` that are associated with a particular CargoType. Meaning this approach is no longer viable. I will update my question to reflect this. Thanks though!

Comment: "creating and destroying the pair for lookup in that scope was far slower". This sounds absolutely incredible and contradicts my own experiments. Show an MCVE.

Comment: How is the current implementation handling the "particular CargoType" requirement? That's not handled in the code anyway, so just keep that as a separate part, the same as it is at the moment. BTW 1: Are the keys (CargoType) really int's? Can you potentially have have a (2*10^9)*(2*10^9) entries in `evaluators`? BTW 2: This has already turned into a discussion. Close this question, create a new one, try to do it MCVE and maybe add a cross-ref between that & this question.